# Windows 10 keeps switching network name after restart even after deleting the profile from reg

Tags: wireless-networking

My computer keeps switching network name after restart even after deleting the profile from reg.
My compter is connecting through wifi with an ssid and when I hover on the wifi signal I see different name (always Network), when Im going to the registry and remove the Network profile and restart the computer it sometimes load with my wifi ssid name as the network and sometimes it brings back the profile I have removed.
please help me fix this.
Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

This is just Windows being Windows.

It is certainly not harmful and does not mean that you are no longer connected
to your SSID.

When you connect, a profile is created for you. But the displayed name is
usually related to the router or adapter or the network name.
There is really no point in changing it, nor in being alarmed about it.